# How to make a Win32 dialog appear at the default position (CW_USEDEFAULT)?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, dialog

How do I make a Win32 **dialog**  appear at the default position/size?

(i.e. How do I simulate `CW_USEDEFAULT` for `CreateWindow` when the window is already created)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a temporary invisible window with `CW_USEDEFAULT` and see where it gets positioned. Move your dialog there.

Comment: I... don't even know what to say... +1

Comment: In all seriousness, is there no less-hacky solution? I feel it's weird to create a new window just to query its position/size.

Comment: There is no "where would you have put a window created with CW_USEDEFAULT" function. The only way to see the effect of CW_USEDEFAULT is to actually create a window. Another solution is to create the invisible window with CW_USEDEFAULT and then create your dialog box as an owned window of the invisible window. Since dialog boxes are positioned relative to their owners, you set the dialog box template position to (0,0). This does affect your owner chain however.

Answer (score 3):

Use the value of CW_USEDEFAULT16, i.e. 0x8000, for both the X and Y positions in the dialog template in the resource file.
For example:

```
IDD_PADDLG DIALOGEX 0x8000, 0x8000, 317, 183
<-- rest of the dialog -->
```