# How to make a window open in a cascade position (using MFC)

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I am using Windows MFC to create a small program.
I would like to make multiple instances of the program appear in a cascaded position(s).

Currently the program always appear centered, i.e. it is not possible to see it multiple windows.

**Is there an automatic way to let windows create multiple instance in cascaded positions?**

To test i use a batch script with multiple lines of:

```
 "start MyProgram.exe"
 "start MyProgram.exe"
 "start MyProgram.exe"
```

The dialogs i use are derived from CDialogEx (but i had same using CDialog)

I expected this to be a flag/properties of the dialog.

Before changing the .rc-file have properties like this

```
IDD_MAIN_DLG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 260, 185 STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SETFOREGROUND | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION
```

**I am aware of the CascadeWindows() function, but to my knowledge it requires more awareness of which instances that already run**

Comment: No there isn't, you have to do this on your own by `MoveWindow`ing the dialog in the `OnInitDialog` method.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812931/how-to-make-a-win32-dialog-appear-at-the-default-position-cw-usedefault

Comment: IMO the c++ and MFC tags should be removed since you want "windows" to do the job without modifying your program

Comment: I do not agree with Robson. I would like to configure my MFC code so that windows could handle it the position... The solution might be outside the scope of MFC though. If other people search for a MFC-solution (like me) they will find out they need to use raw WinApi.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following code as a starting point?

```
#include <Psapi.h>
namespace {
    size_t nWnds = 0;
    HWND hWnds[10];

    BOOL CALLBACK enumerate(HWND hWnd, LPARAM This)
    {
        HWND hWndThis = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(This);

        TCHAR nameThis[MAX_PATH], nameOther[MAX_PATH];
        VERIFY(GetWindowModuleFileName(hWndThis, nameThis, _countof(nameThis)));

        TCHAR wndclass[32];
        VERIFY(RealGetWindowClass(hWnd, wndclass, _countof(wndclass)));

        if (_tcscmp(wndclass, _T("#32770")) == 0) {
            DWORD pid;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
            if (hProcess != NULL) {
                if (GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, nameOther, _countof(nameOther))) {
                    if (_tcscmp(nameThis, nameOther) == 0) {
                        hWnds[nWnds++] = hWnd;
                    }
                }
                VERIFY(CloseHandle(hProcess));
                hProcess = NULL;
            }
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
}

BOOL CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    // ...

    VERIFY(EnumWindows(enumerate, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(m_hWnd)));
    if (nWnds > 1) {
        VERIFY(CascadeWindows(NULL, MDITILE_ZORDER, NULL, nWnds, hWnds));
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

It consists of a change to `OnInitDialog` to scan for all top level dialogs that have been created by your executable and then call `CascadeWindows`. Of course in enumerate you can also move every window you find to a point that starts at `CPoint(x, y)` and changes by `CSize(xoffset, yoffset)` with every found window.

Some things to keep in mind:

1. `CascadeWindows` does not look like the right solution, it restores all maximized windows and does not only touch windows created by your process (which I would prefer).
2. If your process creates multiple top level dialogs, then you might need to detect which dialogs to move.
3. If the user makes a copy of your program file then the module file name will be different.
4. Just proof of concept code, you'll need to add error checking and bounds checking.

Comment: It could be a solution. Seems nice arranged (only a single function call in the initDialog). My aim was however a out-ot-the-box solution from MS. I am not working on my windows tool currently. I will try out this weekend.